# Sort the XML nodes from last to first through XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have below xml structure

```
<head>
  <item>
   <f1>a</f1>
   <f2>b</f2>
  </item>
  <item>
   <f1>c</f1>
   <f2>d</f2>
  </item>
</head>
```

I want the item nodes to be reversed, i.e., from last to first. Please help me with the xslt code for the same.

Comment: From the context of `head`, try using `<xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>` in either an `xsl:apply-templates` or `xsl:for-each`. If you have problems, add the XSLT that you've tried to your question.

Comment: Do you want to reverse the order of the children of a particular element like the `head` element or of all elements?

Comment: I want to reverse the ITEMS nodes only from last to first

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0,

```
<xsl:template match="head">
  <head>
    <xsl:copy-of select="reverse(item)"/>
  </head>
</xsl:template>
```

In XSLT 1.0,

```
<xsl:template match="head">
  <head>
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
      <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </head>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Michael,I have tried both, Same unsorted items nodes only are coming.

Comment: Both solutions work for me with Saxon 9.8, at least if I understood your requirements correctly. Please expand the question by saying what processor you are using and show the exact output you expect, and what you actually get.